# File.renameTo() wont rename and returns false

Tags: android, file

I am trying to make an app where you can select images from your phone and rename them. So far the renameTo() is returning false and not renaming the image but I'm a little lost on why that is so.
I believe I am giving the wrong path name for the file but I need some guidance on this one.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null) {

        Uri photo = data.getData();
        String entirePath = getRealPathFromURI(this, photo);
        String extension = entirePath.substring(entirePath.indexOf("."));
        String imagePath = entirePath.substring(0, entirePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String newImageName = "Blocks";


        File oldName = new File(entirePath);
        File newName = new File(imagePath, newImageName.trim() + extension);

        Log.i("oldName ", entirePath);
        Log.i("newName", imagePath + newImageName.trim() + extension);

        boolean renamed = oldName.renameTo(newName);

        String rename = "no";
        if (renamed)
            rename = "yes";

        Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this, rename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

here are my files oldname and newname

```
 oldName: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20171024_184210.jpg
 newName: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/Blocks.jpg
```

i have these permissions in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you for any input!

Comment: What about permissions? `File.renameTo` requires **write** and **search** permissions

Comment: ok it never asked me for any permissions when doing so let me try putting them in the manifest

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: still a no with those read and write permissions

Comment: have you set also the **search** permission? update your question and post your manifest

Comment: Also try with `Files.move` method suggested in android developer's reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: I would like to keep the api requirement low if at all possible.

Comment: `String entirePath = getRealPathFromURI(this, photo);`. Dont try to get a real path. Its nonsense. Use the uri to rename.

Comment: the uri path is "/-1/1/content://media/external/file/70/ORIGINAL/NONE/1184913684" how can i get the old image name from that?